# Is there a system metric for listview text padding?

Tags: winapi, padding, explorer, getsystemmetrics

In Explorer, when viewing items in details view, there's a little bit of left padding before the text in any given column.  I was wondering if there's a way to obtain that padding value.  I was checking out [`GetSystemMetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics), but I'm not sure if any of those options corresponds to the desired value.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Nope, it's private to the control and undocumented. Seems to be `6 * SM_CXEDGE` though.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps based on this thing that I don't understand, the default might be 3 * SM_CXEDGE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/hdm-getbitmapmargin?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yes I think it's 3 * on each side (6 * total in padding per item). Play around with it until you get something that looks right, basically :)

Comment: If you are interested, you can use the tool to measure, and you can find that the value is roughly the same as 3 * SM_CXEDGE. By the way, what is the purpose of doing this?